# Trying to run script in Powershell just hangs on cursor at end of script

Tags: powershell

I have found [this PowerShell script](http://rk13log.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/export-and-import-ntfs-permission-with.html), and link, all over the web with other variants. Its a simple script to export NTFS file permissions to CSV file, so I can later edit and put in a new domain name. Then import it back with another script.

When I try to run the script, replacing my variable, PowerShell just hangs on the cursor. It does this on the 5 servers I tested on. What am I doing wrong running this script? Have I copied and pasted it wrong or do I have to do something else in PowerShell to make it work

This is the script I am trying to run:

```
    Get-ChildItem "C:" -Recurse | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{ $Path = $_.FullName
    # Exclude inherited rights from the report
    (Get-Acl $Path).Access | ?{ !$_.IsInherited } | Select-Object `
    @{n='Path';e={ $Path }}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType, `
    InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags, FileSystemRights } | Export-CSV "c:\temp\Permissions.csv"
```

Comment: fix the `$.` with `$_.` at `$.PsIsContainer` and `$.FullName`

Comment: When you say "hangs", you know you have to press enter twice, right? And that you are listing and getting every file and folder, and then filtering out the files, and then getting the ACL on every folder on the C drive, which is likely to be some quarter million things or more, and there won't be any visible output while it runs?

Comment: Thanks Micky and JPBlanc. Rookie mistake, i did hit Enter a second time as the cursor was hanging at the end of the script and this time it worked and the permissions.csv file was created. Problem i have now is that if i change the path "C:\" to a single folder to test such as "C:\TestFolder" there is NO output. But if i leave the C:\ entry in my example it DOES output all of C (well most of C because as you are right Micky doing all of C can take a while so i did a Ctrl+C to break) with exception of same tables showing a numeric long number. Anything I need to do to get one folder working?

Answer (score 0):

Retry with this one :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\"  | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{ $Path = $_.FullName; (Get-Acl $Path).Access | ?{ !$_.IsInherited } | Select-Object @{n='Path';e={ $Path }}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType, InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags, FileSystemRights } | Export-CSV "c:\temp\Permissions.csv"
```

Keep it one line, I change `$.PsIsContainer` to `$_.PsIsContainer`, `$.FullName` to `$_.FullName;` to correct the syntax and separate the instruction, I remove the comment. It works for me like that.

Comment: Thanks JP, i did find out that my issue was i was not hitting Enter a second time and it worked after that but now my issue is in the comment i added in Micky's post. Can you help on how to output just one folder? Oh,and i did try with your edited one line script and works also only with C but only outputs like 20 lines and does not go as long as the original script. I would be more than happy to use yours as well. Thanks, Jimmy K